# NavigationLink inside a ControlGroup

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to create a series of links within a ControlGroup like so:

```
ControlGroup {
   NavigationLink(destination: BranchView(branches: mockBranches)) {
      Button("Branches") {
         print("clicked")
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

- The button doesn't show any animation and print doesn't run.
- Replacing the Button element with Text does not fix this.
- The same code works fine outside the ControlGroup

Google is surprisingly sparse about the combination of the two. I'm beginning to think that I missed something about ControlGroup and it's not intended to be used like this.

Edit:

As noted below, this is due to the migration from NavigationView. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `NavigationLink` inside a `NavigationStack` for it to work.
Also `NavigationLink` is already a button, so there is no need for the `Button("Branches")`.

Here is some code that shows `NavigationLink` working inside a `ControlGroup`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ControlGroup {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination")) {
                    Text("tap this link")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I used NavigationView and it worked outside. I was following the wwdc tutorial and did not assume such a breaking change.